# Local Searching in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to search a list or library item in SharePoint 2013. We have a big list. We need to search the item on the home web part page. Its working IE, but doesn't work properly in chrome and also the fields have an issue ? I need help ? Thanks

```
<input type="text" style="width:350px" id="txtSearch" />
<input type="button" style=" font-size:15px;font-family:'Segoe UI 
Light','Segoe UI','Segoe',Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-
color:#0072C6; color:white" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return 
search();" />
<style>
.highlight {
background-color: #FFFF88;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://my.ABC.com/sites/sandbox1/TEST/test/SiteAssets/jqueryy-
3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 /*
 *This is jQuery Highlight plugin to highlight the result text

 */

jQuery.extend({
highlight: function (node, re, nodeName, className) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var match = node.data.match(re);
        if (match) {
            var highlight = document.createElement(nodeName || 'span');
            highlight.className = className || 'highlight';
            var wordNode = node.splitText(match.index);
            wordNode.splitText(match[0].length);
            var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
            highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
            wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
            return 1; //skip added node in parent
        }
    } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element 
nodes that have children
            !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and 
style nodes
            !(node.tagName === nodeName.toUpperCase() && node.className === 
className)) { // skip if already highlighted
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, 
className);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
});

jQuery.fn.unhighlight = function (options) {
var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span' };
jQuery.extend(settings, options);

return this.find(settings.element + "." + settings.className).each(function 
() {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
    parent.normalize();
}).end();
};

jQuery.fn.highlight = function (words, options) {
var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span', caseSensitive: 
false, wordsOnly: false };
jQuery.extend(settings, options);

if (words.constructor === String) {
    words = [words];
}
words = jQuery.grep(words, function(word, i){
  return word != '';
});
words = jQuery.map(words, function(word, i) {
  return word.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
});
if (words.length == 0) { return this; };

var flag = settings.caseSensitive ? "" : "i";
var pattern = "(" + words.join("|") + ")";
if (settings.wordsOnly) {
    pattern = "\\b" + pattern + "\\b";
}
var re = new RegExp(pattern, flag);

return this.each(function () {
    jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className);
});
};

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function search()

      {


       $("#tasksUL").empty();
      var qry= document.getElementById("txtSearch").value
  var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems 
xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Test</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
 <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
  </viewFields> \
  <query> \
   <Query> 
<Where> 
<or> 
<Contains>
```

"+qry+"

```
<Contains>
```

"+qry+"

```
<Contains>
```

"+qry+"

```
</Query> \
  </query> \
   </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: 
"https://my.ABC.com/sites/sandbox1/Training/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });

  }


function processResult(xData, status) {
// show searching text and image when search button is clicked
var loadhtml="<div id='loading' class='ms-dlgLoadingTextDiv'><span 
style='padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 10px;'><img width='24' height='24' 
title='This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to 
remove this animated image.' src='/_layouts/15/images/gears_anv4.gif?
rev=36'/></span><span class='ms-core-pageTitle ms-accentText'>Searching...
</span></div>";

//var totalRows = $(xData.responseXML).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");
var totalRows =   getZRows(xData.responseXML);
if(totalRows=="0")
{
 $("#loading").remove();
$("#tasksUL").before("<div  id='loading'  style='color:red;font-
size:15px'>No matching records found. Please refine your search.</div>");
return true;
}
$("#tasksUL").before(loadhtml);
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() {

// creating hyperlink for each item to display form of that list item
var lnk="<a 
href='https://my.ABC.com/sites/sandbox1/Training/Lists/Test/DispForm.aspx?
ID=" + $(this).attr('ows_ID') + "'>"+ $(this).attr("ows_Title") +"</a>";

        var liHtml = "<li>"+ lnk+"</li>";

// 2 second delay and show searching text and image also highlight the 
result with the searched keyword
setTimeout(function(){
 $("#loading").remove();
 $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
$("#tasksUL > li").highlight(document.getElementById("txtSearch").value);
}, 2000);

    });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
// check if enter button is pressed and then search button clicked event is 
called
$('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13)
  $('#btnSearch').click();
});
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getZRows(rXML) {
 var rows;
 var itemCount = $(rXML).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");
if (rXML.getElementsByTagName("z:row").length == 0 && itemCount == 
undefined) {
rows = rXML.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "row");
} else {
rows = rXML.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
}
return rows.length;
 }
</script>

<div id="search_result">
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
</div>
```

Comment: try this one http://sharepointerz.blogspot.com.au/2014/05/search-sharepoint-list-items-using.html

Comment: I wanna put 8 fields to search in a list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try the following JS and let me know  .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;};

$(document).ready(function(){

    var webPartID = $("#WebPartWPQ3");

    $(webPartID).prepend('<div style="padding: 2px; margin: 5px auto 0pt;  display: block;"><h3 style="text-align: left;margin:2px;">Document search: <input type="text" placeholder="Type your text here..."; border: 1px solid rgb(18,105,159); class="search" style="padding: 5px;"/></h3></div>');

        $("input.search").change(function() {
            var txt = $("input.search").val();
            if (txt) {
                $(webPartID).find("td:not(:Contains("+txt+"))").parent("tr.ms-itmhover").hide();
                $(webPartID).find("td:Contains("+txt+")").parent("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
            } else {
                $(webPartID).find("td").parent("tr.ms-itmhover").show();
            }
        }).keyup(function(){$(this).change();
    })
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this code and it is worked.

1. Change the listname to your listname. My current list called **TestList**.
2. Change the url. Mine for example i put as example www.contoso.com and replace with your sitecollection url.
3. Change the column that you want to search. Currently i search using **Title**
4. change your result link to the list `http://contoso.com/TestList/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + $(this).attr('ows_ID') + "'>"+ $(this).attr("ows_Title") +"</a>`
5. Put all the following script in **Script Editor webpart**

   ```
   <input type="text" style="width:350px" id="txtSearch" />
    <input type="button" style=" font-size:15px;font-family:'Segoe UI Light','Segoe UI','Segoe',Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#0072C6; color:white" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return search();" />
       <style>
       .highlight {
           background-color: #FFFF88;
       }
       </style>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">



   jQuery.extend({
       highlight: function (node, re, nodeName, className) {
           if (node.nodeType === 3) {
               var match = node.data.match(re);
               if (match) {
                   var highlight = document.createElement(nodeName || 'span');
                   highlight.className = className || 'highlight';
                   var wordNode = node.splitText(match.index);
                   wordNode.splitText(match[0].length);
                   var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
                   highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
                   wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
                   return 1; //skip added node in parent
               }
           } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element nodes that have children
                   !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and style nodes
                   !(node.tagName === nodeName.toUpperCase() && node.className === className)) { // skip if already highlighted
               for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                   i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, className);
               }
           }
           return 0;
       }
   });

   jQuery.fn.unhighlight = function (options) {
       var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span' };
       jQuery.extend(settings, options);

       return this.find(settings.element + "." + settings.className).each(function () {
           var parent = this.parentNode;
           parent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
           parent.normalize();
       }).end();
   };

   jQuery.fn.highlight = function (words, options) {
       var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span', caseSensitive: false, wordsOnly: false };
       jQuery.extend(settings, options);

       if (words.constructor === String) {
           words = [words];
       }
       words = jQuery.grep(words, function(word, i){
         return word != '';
       });
       words = jQuery.map(words, function(word, i) {
         return word.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
       });
       if (words.length == 0) { return this; };

       var flag = settings.caseSensitive ? "" : "i";
       var pattern = "(" + words.join("|") + ")";
       if (settings.wordsOnly) {
           pattern = "\\b" + pattern + "\\b";
       }
       var re = new RegExp(pattern, flag);

       return this.each(function () {
           jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className);
       });
   };

   </script>


   <script type="text/javascript">
               function search()

             {


              $("#tasksUL").empty();
             var qry= document.getElementById("txtSearch").value
     var soapEnv =
               "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                   <soapenv:Body> \
                        <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                           <listName>TestList</listName> \
                           <viewFields> \
                               <ViewFields> \
                                  <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                              </ViewFields> \
         </viewFields> \
         <query> \
          <Query> \
   <Where> \
   <Contains> \
            <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
            <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
         </Contains> \
         </Where> \
   </Query> \
         </query> \
         </GetListItems> \
                   </soapenv:Body> \
               </soapenv:Envelope>";

           $.ajax({
               url: "http://contoso.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "xml",
               data: soapEnv,
               complete: processResult,
               contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
           });

     }




       function processResult(xData, status) {
   // show searching text and image when search button is clicked
   var loadhtml="<div id='loading' class='ms-dlgLoadingTextDiv'><span style='padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 10px;'><img width='24' height='24' title='This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to remove this animated image.' src='/_layouts/15/images/gears_anv4.gif?rev=36'/></span><span class='ms-core-pageTitle ms-accentText'>Searching...</span></div>";

       var totalRows = parseFloat($(xData.responseXML).find('[nodeName="rs:data"]').attr("ItemCount"));
   if(totalRows=="0")
   {
    $("#loading").remove();
   $("#tasksUL").before("<div  id='loading'  style='color:red;font-size:15px'>No matching records found. Please refine your search.</div>");
   return true;
   }
   $("#tasksUL").before(loadhtml);
           $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {

   // creating hyperlink for each item to display form of that list item
   var lnk="<a href='http://contoso.com/TestList/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + $(this).attr('ows_ID') + "'>"+ $(this).attr("ows_Title") +"</a>";

               var liHtml = "<li>"+ lnk+"</li>";

   // 2 second delay and show searching text and image also highlight the result with the searched keyword
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("#loading").remove();
      $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
     $("#tasksUL > li").highlight(document.getElementById("txtSearch").value);
   }, 2000);

           });

       }

   $(document).ready(function(){
   // check if enter button is pressed and then search button clicked event is called
       $('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e){
         if(e.keyCode==13)
         $('#btnSearch').click();
       });
   });
   </script>
   // show search result in the ul 
   <div id="search_result">
   <ul id="tasksUL"/>
   </div>
   ```

You can have a look the post from:
http://sharepointerz.blogspot.com.au/2014/05/search-sharepoint-list-items-using.html

Comment: I changed the name but It searched no output. Here is the info.            
1-My list name is Country contacts                                                            2-the link is :           https://my.ABC.org/sites/sandbox1/countryprograms/test/Pages/Country%20Programs.aspx and                                                                              3-We have 8 fields eg. FName,Lname,Email,...How can I fix . Thanks

Comment: what field you want to search? and can you please put the code that you have so far

Comment: I sent again could you check it please ?